# Possible to ship my application with a local copy of the .NET 7 runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, .net-7.0

Having a set of multiple .NET 7 applications (Console and WinForms) that all sit in the same folder of a product of mine, I try to find a way to deploy it.

Ideally I do *not* want the .NET 7 Desktop runtime to be installed as a prerequisite condition. I also do *not* want to publish every of my multiple .NET applications as "Self-contained", since this would enlarge the whole product deployment package as everyone of the several applications has its own copy of .NET 7.

My ideal solution would be to have all my .NET applications sit in one folder and additionally have the full .NET Desktop runtime and all of its files also sit in that very same folder so that all my .NET applications do use this local copy of the .NET Desktop runtime.

I've read through "[.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)" but still found no way to do this.

#### My question

Is it possible to "side-by-side" deploy the .NET 7 runtime together with my application(s)?

#### Edit 1

I wasn't fully aware that "Self-contained" and "Produce single file" are two independent switches.

Thanks to [Bron Davies' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76183213/107625) I now am.

I do think turning "Self-contained" on but leaving "Produce single file" off for one of my multiple applications could be sufficient to serve as the runtime for all of my distinct applications in the final folder.

#### Edit 2

I've [asked the question over at GitHub.com](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/85826) and there are several additional answers to those here, maybe someone reading it here might also be interested in the Q&A over there.

Comment: When you publish application the Runtime version of Net 7 is part of the install package.

Comment: I do not think there is any easy or convenient way to do what you want. But .Net is open source, so you should be able to hack something together if you spend enough time and effort on it. As long as you have all the .net files you should be able to use [`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) to launch a framework dependent assembly, at least in principle. But the documentation recommends not using this for production.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: This is called AoT (Ahead of Time), and a lot of work has been done in recent years to make this possible in many (not all) situations. You WILL have to bundle .Net with each app for this, but each app does NOT have to bundle the _entire_ framework: only those parts the app actually uses. Unfortunately, I don't think AoT is supported yet for WinForms, but the Console Apps might be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive discussion on this topic here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3453

and here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53834

Unfortunately it pretty much ends up with the answer that it's not currently possible but with some attention to the issue (i.e. upvotes), a solution might be developed.

Comment: OMG, I wasn't fully aware that "Self-contained" and "Produce single file" are two independent switches. I do think turning "Self-contained" on but leaving "Produce single file" off for one of my multiple applications could be sufficient to serve as the runtime for all of my distinct applications in the final folder.